# How to read different file encodings in C++ without ICU?

Tags: c++, encoding, utf-8, icu

I want to create a program able to read and write files in different encodings, e.g. Ansi or UTF-8, possibly more. I want the user to be able to select the encoding via a command line option, so the program should be able to find a de-/encoder from a given name.

I know that this can easily be done with ICU; however, I don't want to use this library due to its massive size: The program itself is less than a Megabyte while ICU is about 20MB. Are there any other options for easy transcoding of files?

Comment: Have you read: http://site.icu-project.org/charts/icu4c-footprint  ?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to re-invent `iconv` or `recode`.

Comment: @Richard Critten: I actually did not, so thanks for the link, it's quite enlightening.

Comment: @Eljay: No, I actually don't want to just change the encoding of files (I have to admit, I worded my question ambiguously there), instead I want to create a parser for certain files that can come in any common encoding.

Comment: On what platform(s)?